# FAILURE answer from kie-server (using kie-server-showcase and business-central-workbench-showcase)

Tags: drools, kie-server

I am testing business-central with kie-server both running in docker, both are "showcase" versions. I've made project in business-central with "Cow" model ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD6sS.png)) and decision table ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIasa.png)) for it. Build & Deploy is successful.

After sending json with request body

```
{
    "commands:": [
        {
            "insert": {
                "object": {
                    "Cow": {
                        "name": "cow1",
                        "age": 11
                    }
                },
                "out-identifier": "Cow",
                "return-object": true
            }
        },
        {
            "fire-all-rules": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

to endpoint
`http://localhost:8180/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/instances/Cow`

receiving an error:

```
{
    "type": "FAILURE",
    "msg": "Bad request, no commands to be executed - either wrong format or no data",
    "result": null
}
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong? Why my request doesn't proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your request you need the canonical class name `com.axaukraine.Cow`, but you are using just the simple name `Cow`.

```
{
    "commands:": [
        {
            "insert": {
                "object": {
                    "com.axaukraine.Cow": {
                        "name": "cow1",
                        "age": 11
                    }
                },
                "out-identifier": "Cow",
                "return-object": true
            }
        },
        {
            "fire-all-rules": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Since this issue was a long time ago we made a decision to not use business-central and I can't check the request. But thanks for your comment. Yep it could be true that i made a mistake in package path